# Guidewire Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, guidewire, gosu

I am trying to enable clustering in one of the higher environments. The changes which I did was enabling the clustering flag to true in **context.xml** and added the server roles in the java properties class in the server. Apart from this do we need to add anything? I am not able to access the application via load balancing ip. Also, I am getting rolling/full upgrade exception while starting one of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify GW module and version. You can look up the documentation here
https://docs.guidewire.com/portal/secure/doc/pc/PolicyCenter_8.0.4/doc/System%20Administration%20Guide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=clustering.08.07.html

If you doesn't have GW User, same documentation are in GW Module Folder/doc
[image: doc folder]

Comment: It is version 9. I do not have access to the mentioned link

Comment: OK. Verify in module folder, it's the same documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to enable clustering in one of the higher environments. The changes which I did was enabling the clustering flag to true in context.xml and added the server roles in the java properties class in the server.

I guess you mean to say config.xml file. As per documentation you should enable clustering and configuration verification per env selected (I guess you did since you were getting the other error).

> Apart from this do we need to add anything?

If you have added the registry for your node names with roles, then you should have the nodes have proper server ID flag set. If you don't have the registry in your config.xml though you can have the roles defined on the server id JVM flag with suffix `#roles_list` for example `policycenter-online0#workqueue,messaging`.

> I am not able to access the application via load balancing ip.

Well this sounds like LB issue, your LB should be smart enough to have you stick to single node for sticky session. You should check the logs and analyze where the requests get to and if there are any exception thrown if it gets to GW.

> Also, I am getting rolling/full upgrade exception while starting one of the server.

This one sounds like this single node is trying to start on code that's not matching what the other nodes run on. (verifying the data model changes - that's when your server mode is TEST or higher, and then the configuration changes - that's the verify configuration flag in config.xml).